# Getting errors when i try to get game to restart when i hit an obstacle or fall of ground

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Please excuse me I'm a complete novice at all this but I'm  trying to make a game following "Brackeys How To Make A Video Game" I'm on video 8 if that helps. I can't seem to find what i have done wrong i have added my scripts for "player movement", "player collision" and "game manager". Please if there is anything else you need to help me please ask i really don't want to give up just yet was really enjoying doing this.
Thank you all

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    // This is a reference to the Rigidbody component called "rb"
    public Rigidbody rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;  // Variable that determines the forward force
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;  // Variable that determines the sideways force

    // We marked this as "Fixed"Update because we
    // are using it to mess with physics.
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Add a forward force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))  // If the player is pressing the "d" key
        {
            // Add a force to the right
            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))  // If the player is pressing the "a" key
        {
            // Add a force to the left
            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

public PlayerMovement movement;     // A reference to our PlayerMovement script

    // This function runs when we hit another object.
    // We get information about the collision and call it "collisionInfo".
    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo)
    {
        // We check if the object we collided with has a tag called "Obstacle".
        if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Obstacle")
        {
            movement.enabled = false;   // Disable the players movement.
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

    bool gameHasEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;

    public GameObject completeLevelUI;

    public void CompleteLevel ()
    {
        completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);
    }

    public void EndGame ()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GAME OVER");
            Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
        }
    }

    void Restart ()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

}
```

when i fall off ground:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerMovement.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs:32)

when i hit an obstacle:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerCollision.OnCollisionEnter (UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerCollision.cs:15)

Comment: Did you check whether "rb" (in PlayerMovement.cs) and "movement" (in PlayerCollision.cs) are not null?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `FindObjectOfType<GameManager>()` is returning null, which is causing a null reference exception when you attempt to call the `EndGame` function. This most likely means that there is no object in your scene with the `GameManager` component on it. The solution to this problem is simple:

Create an empty object in your scene and add the `GameManager` component to it. This will fix the error in this instance, but it could happen in the future if you're not careful. It is also a good idea to check if you found an object or not before calling functions on it:

```
GameManager gm = FindObjectOfType<GameManager>();
if (gm != null)
{
    gm.EndGame();
}
```